# AS3 / removeChild/addChild by clicking button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have several movie clips into a frame the size of the stage and I have to switch through a button between those pages.

So if I press button, should all the other frames removeChild and the one where he is called to go addChild.

Edit: I have the actionscript placed in the timeline of the movieClip so the button is not on the stage but I put in the movie clip using action script.

So what DodgerThud showed here is not possible because the button has changed since that is in the movieClip('s).

I think I need to place the same code in every movieClip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of your MovieClips into a Vector or Array.

When you click the button, you should cycle through the Vector/Array and check if the MovieClip is currently on stage with `contains(DisplayObject)`. If the Movieclip IS currently on the stage, remove it and add another one to the stage, for example, the next one in the Vector/Array.

```
var vec:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>
vec[0] = new MovieClip();
vec[1] = new MovieClip();  //example with MovieClips
vec[2] = new MovieClip();

addChild(vec[0]);  //add one of the MovieClips to stage

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < vec.length; i++) //go through the Vector one by one
    {
         if(contains(vec[i])  //if the Object at position i in the Vector is on stage
         {
              removeChild(vec[i]); //remove the Object
              var next:int = i;    //create a temporary holder
              if(next == vec.length) //check if the displayed Object was the last in the list
              {
                   next = 0;  //if so, set to 0
              }else{
                   next++; //otherwise, only add 1
              }
              addChild(vec[next]); //add the next Object to the stage. If the removed Object was the last in the Vector, it'll add the first Object in the Vector to the list
              break; //escape the for loop, otherwise it'll always only show the last Object
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 74 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.` This is what i get?

Comment: @Adorably please post the code where the error gets thrown, around Line 74.

Comment: Sorry it was at line 13. `Knop1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
`

Comment: What is probably happening here is that Knop1 is not an Object, but a Class. addEventListener is not a static function, so you have to create Knop1 first before you can use its functions.

Comment: I made a symbol, a button and placed it on the stage with an AS Linkage "Knop1"

Comment: Yes, the Linkage is a class. If you placed the button on the stage, select it and look for the properties panel on the upper right of Flash. you should be able to give it a name. You can reference this name in your code then. otherwise, you need to create the Object in your code like `var b:Knop1 = new Knop1()`

Comment: I did not have to do AS Linkage.
Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation

I forgot to mention that the button is not on the stage but in every movie clip. So I need for each movieclip an action script. Is this is still possible?

Comment: Should i make a new question that you answer there?

Comment: or rather, edit your question and explain your problem as best as you can

Answer (score 0):

Something like ...

```
function tueHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  while(numChildren > 0)
    removeChildAt(0);
  addChild(whatever);
}
```

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 74 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.